# jQuery's click/"unclick"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently developing navigation for my friend's site. I use event binding like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.title-container h1 a, .img-container a', function() {
    showPosts();

    return false;
});
```

What I need is a jQuery's function or something that will undo this previous `click`. I'm trying to avoid using this two times, I'm thinking - is there something similar to `hover` (which has two arguments) that I can use with this?

Long story short - I want something like http://api.jquery.com/hover/ only for `click`.

`showPosts()` is loading a post using `$.get`. What I want: when I click on this post again, I want to fire `unShowPosts()` function.

I hope this clears it somehow. Sorry, my English is pretty bad, as it seems.

Comment: what you mean by undo??

Comment: Do you mean you only want the event to fire once? If so, use `one()`

Comment: You could use `toggle` in your `showPosts`

Comment: By undo if you mean hiding the posts then you can use toggle as @abhitalks said. And if you want that click not to perform if posts are already shown then you need to check their visibility or if they have some class or even they exist based upon your structure before showing

Comment: There used to be a [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) event, but that was deprecated in v1.8 (removed in v1.9)

Comment: @SimonAdcock: yes. that's why i suggested `toggle` in `showPosts`. it is unclear from the question about what showposts does. but i am assuming it could use some `slideToggle` / `fadeToggle` kinda thing.

Comment: @abhitalks yep, and that's why I +1'd your comment ;) I was just adding info about the toggle event just in case the OP was interested.

Comment: Oh, Ok. Am sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: Simply providing a jsFiddle would give you accurate answer in no time

Comment: @tomek: Here, I have created a template fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/4r6Yk/ Please clarify your use-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `.data()` usage like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.title-container h1 a, .img-container a', function () {  
   $(this).data('clicked', !$(this).data('clicked'));     
   $(this).data('clicked') ?  showPosts() : unShowPosts(); 
});
```

Comment: But then `unShowPosts()` will always be called because you are setting `.data()` before checking it

Comment: After first click, `$(this).data('clicked') !== 'clicked'` will always be `false`. It could be instead: `$(document).on('click', '.title-container h1 a, .img-container a', function () {
    $(this).data('clicked', !$(this).data('clicked'));
    $(this).data('clicked') ?  showPosts() : unShowPosts();
});`

Comment: @A.Wolff i really get confused with the use of `.data()` i did it still confused.....

Comment: @A.Wolff: Per the latest comment from Op [(down below)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038039/jquerys-click-unclick#comment37057928_24038092), your 2nd comment seems to be "the" answer.

Comment: @abhitalks I'd let Jai modify his answer because he was the first to post answer using `data` object  ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff you are Awesome man, eyes & brain, how did you train...`:)`

Comment: @Jai I'm playing angry bird, that's my training... ;)

Comment: @Jai You’ll quickly run into race conditions when you have multiple triggers: http://jsfiddle.net/2eus8/

Comment: Well, click one trigger and show posts. Then click another and... show posts again. Then hide it using the first trigger. etc etc. I think you need a global flag for this, not attached to the action node.

Comment: @David But looks like expected behaviour. Otherwise, your answer would be more accurate indeed. And anyway, that's how work pseudo event `hover` whom OP was referring to in question

Comment: @A.Wolff Well that depends... not much info from the OP but since `showPosts()` is global you can assume that you don’t want this to fire twice when clicking on different links

Comment: @David Makes sense in this case, btw, OP is using plurial here `showPosts()`, so sounds like you are correct

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set your event off with: `.off(...)` on click and to register a new one which will call your other function.

See details: http://api.jquery.com/off/

```
function unshowPost() { ... }

function showPost() {

    ...
    // Remove current event...
    $(document).off('click', '.title-container h1 a, .img-container a', showPost);
    // Register a new one to trigger "unshowPost" function.
    $(document).on('click', '.title-container h1 a, .img-container a', unshowPost);

    return false;
}

$(document).on('click', '.title-container h1 a, .img-container a', showPost);
```

See behaviour here: http://jsfiddle.net/XTCEr/1/

Comment: This will make the event to work only once, then will not work no more.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown And that's what is asked for... Look: "I'm trying to avoid using this two times"

Comment: What I try to avoid is using `click` two times. And your solution isn't what I'm looking for after all.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski You want to make your link disabled?

Comment: Yeah, what you said makes sense. The question is too unclear.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski I edited my answer. Try it in JSfiddle. Does it suit your needs now?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var hidden = true
$(document).on('click', '.title-container h1 a, .img-container a', function() {
    hidden = !hidden ? hidePosts() : showPosts()
});
```

Comment: But then this is not specific to element already clicked, or not ***EDIT*** but ya could be it, depending what is expecting as behaviour OP